# My VBA sub routine stops running after the line with the convert to linked data type (Stocks) command

Tags: excel, vba

Here is part of the code I am trying to run. You can see the line I commented on where the subroutine stops running (just ends)

```
dados.Activate
unProtect_sheets
dados.Cells(2, "f").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF([@[Ativos 24]]="""","""",VLOOKUP([@[Ativos 24]],WebQuery,3,FALSE))"

    Data.Activate
    unProtect_sheets
    
    If Not Cells(2, 1).Value = "" Then
        Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row, 4)).Clear
    End If
    Worksheets("Dados").Activate
    Range(dados.Cells(2, 1), dados.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
            
    Data.Activate

    Data.Cells(2, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
   Range("B2", Cells(Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row, 2)).Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""BVMF:""&[@[DADOS]]"
    
    
    Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row, 4)).Select
    Selection.Clear
     
    
    Range("B2", Cells(Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row, 2)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
   
    Range("b2", Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ConvertToLinkedDataType ServiceID:=268435456, LanguageCulture:= _
                                                                       "en-US"
```

***** the code stops running here. It just ends the sub routine after the line above

```
    Protect_sheets
    Cells(x, "c").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=[@Column1].Price"
    Cells(x, "d").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=[@Column1].[Change(%)]"
```

Comment: Do you have an on error resume next earlier in the code?